# what determines what parts of the talmud(if any) are in hebrew rather than aramaic?

Tags: hebrew, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi, tractate-sotah

I read in this question

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226412/origins-of-turn-over-in-his-grave-turn-over-in-her-grave-etc-etc/226478?noredirect=1#comment576934_226478

That this line in Sora 7b is in Hebrew and not in Aramaic.

In there, in Sotah 7b, it says (in the English translation by Soncino):

```
All the years that the Israelites were in the wilderness, Judah's bones kept turning in his coffin until Moses arose and begged mercy for him.
```

And the original Hebrew

```
כל אותן שנים שהיו ישראל במדבר היו עצמותיו של יהודה מגולגלין בארון עד שעמד משה ובקש עליו רחמים
```

And that parts of the Talmud Bavli are in Hebrew.

I can guess that the Mishna is in Mishnaic Hebrew, but the passage is from the Gemara

Why is that passage in Hebrew?

And what other parts of the Gemara are in Hebrew?

Is there any order at all as to which parts are Hebrew and which Aramaic?

And where there is hebrew, what's the largest chunk that one gets.. A daf(page)? a masechet(tractate)?

And is it the same with the Talmud Yerushalmi?

And is there any English translation online that states whether what it is translating is Hebrew or Aramaic?

Comment: Besides just the "Mishna section" of the page, the Gemara often quotes Mishnayot from other locations as well as Beraitot (which are also Tannaic statements which are generally in Hebrew). Sometimes the Gemara does just speak in Hebrew, though.

Comment: @Daniel  Well I suppose the Mishna section isn't the Gemara. Fair point re when it quotes a Mishna. But what was the cause for it speaking that quoted line  in Hebrew?

Comment: Probably the medrash quoted was old enough to have been in Hebrew. The Aramaic is only when it is "contemporary" with the gemara.

Comment: @sabbahillel when you say quotes a medrash, is that a midrash like midrash rabba? in which case, what midrash is it quoting from?

Comment: @barlop often the midrashim are only preserved in the text of the Gemara. That might be the case here (I don't know)

Comment: @barlop I mean that the quotes are from previous generations handed down orally and not a contemporaneous discussion of what was said in the Bais Medrash. Thus, it is quoted in the language of the time it was originally said.

Comment: There are multiple collections of midrashim (Rabbah, Tanchuma, Yalkut). Additionally, the Talmud Yerushalmi is mostly written in Israeli-Aramaic, a different but related dialect from Babylonian-Aramaic. Which makes sense when you consider that the two were separated by very large distances and had different local cultures.

Comment: An older more experienced chavrusa of mine once made the observation that the more halachicaly oriented a statement is, the more likely it will be in lashon hakodesh. The more it falls into the category of drush, the more likely it is to be and or have many words in Aramaic or Latin. This seems to hold true to a large degree, but it is not foolproof. If you are really brave you can use this as a sniff (corroborate) to prove a point. He liked to point to חייב איניש לבסומי בפוריא which many achronim say not to take literally, which is written in Aramaic.

Comment: re everyone who has been talking about Gemaras quoting Midrashim: it doesn't happen. Both are Amoraim and thus the same *teachings* might appear across the various works, but Gemaras don't quote Midrashim like it would a Mishnah or a Braisa. Thus, the language wouldn't change based on that.